# Which URL are you supposed to use for the twitter oEmbed API?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, oembed

I'm trying to embed tweets based on users' search terms.

I can retrieve tweets from Twitter's search API, but then none of the URLs I get back in twitter's response are compatible with the oEmbed API, so I can't display the tweets I'm getting.

I send a `GET` to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=${VARIABLE}`, and here are all of the URLs I get back:

```
display_url: "twitter.com/i/web/status/1…"
expanded_url: "https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1328842765115920384"
url: [shortened URL that Stack Overflow will not let me print]
```

However, for the oEmbed API, the url needs to be in the format of `https://twitter.com/[username]/status/[id]`.

Can anyone help as to how I can utilise the search api and then display those tweets on screen?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is that you have retrieved truncated Tweets, and you need the full Tweet in order to have the correct URL.

First of all, add `?tweet_mode=extended` to the API call. This parameter is needed in API v1.1 in order to retrieve Tweets that are longer than 140 characters.

`GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=${VARIABLE}&tweet_mode=extended`

Once you've done that, you'll have the full Tweet object. However, it will not contain a link to itself - the only reason you had the link before is that you were retrieving the truncated Tweet, so the API returned a link to the complete Tweet.

The way to construct the original Tweet URL is to combine the Tweet ID with a Twitter status URL. It doesn't matter what username you put in, because Twitter will resolve that from the ID.

So in this case, you have Tweet ID `1328842765115920384`, and you can append it to `https://twitter.com/twitter/status/` to give `https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1328842765115920384` which will resolve to `https://twitter.com/Ashton5SOS/status/1328842765115920384` automatically.

Pass this URL to the publish.twitter.com oEmbed endpoint.

There's more information in [this DEV post](https://dev.to/twitterdev/getting-to-the-canonical-url-for-a-tweet-85e).